# Unknown y_type for KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run KNeighborClassifier on some numpy arrays and I've been getting the error `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'`

The type of my X_matrix and my y_vector are both
`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and the shape for the two respectivley are

`(46, 240)
(46,)`

Both the X_matrix and y_vector contain only ints. The y_vector only containing 1s and 0s.

Any help will be greatley appreciated.

Comment: You should post the complete stack trace of error. What kind of values are present in `y`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing label (y) data to  KNeighborClassifier `classifier.fit(X_matrix ,y_vector)`, it expects `y_vector` to be 1D list.

```
y_vector=list(y_vector.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the shape of the numpy arrays:

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

y = np.array( [0,1,0,1,0] )
x=np.array( [ [2.3,5.3,6.8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5] ] )
x=x.reshape(5,2)

clf=KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(x,y)

# check type and shape
type(x)
x.shape
type(y)
y.shape
```

Result:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

(5L, 2L)

(5L,)
```

If you want to predict using the fitted clf:

```
x_new = np.array( [10, 20] )
x_new = x_new.reshape(1,2)
clf.predict(x_new)
```

Result:

```
array([0])
```